# Linq querying local collections against database

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I'm querying my local list against database and would like to know what's the best way to do so.

Currently I'm loading my database to memory where "options" in local List

```
tmp.AddRange(from course in cs.studhists.Where(x => x.year == year).AsEnumerable()
                         from option in options.Where(x => x.type.Equals("course"))
                         join stud in cs.sstudents on course.studid equals stud.studid
                         where
                         course.csid.Contains(option.identifier) && course.crsinst.Contains(option.extra_identifier)
                         select stud);
```

"studhists" table has quite a few rows and if I didn't have option to select only the ones with current year or if year was inside option object it would take a while to load to memory.

Alternatively I could just loop through every option (which worked a lot faster before I figured out to load only data with current year. I haven't timed it, but I think it still does.

```
foreach (OptionListItem opt in options.Where(x => x.type.Equals("course")))
{
   tmp.AddRange(from course in cs.studhists
                join stud in cs.sstudents on course.studid equals stud.studid
                where course.year == year
                && course.csid.Contains(opt.identifier) && course.crsinst.Contains(opt.extra_identifier)
                select stud);
}
```

Is there a way to maybe create temp table to hold "options" and query it?

Or am I completely missing some other way to do this?

Comment: Which lists are local and which are coming from the database?

Comment: How does an "option" relate to a `course.csid`? What is a `course.csid`? or a `course.csrinst`?

Comment: "options" is local list, it's a set of rules selected. There are different rules looking up different tables, hence
 
    `options.Where(x => x.type.Equals("course"))`

 it may need 1 or 2 fields depending on table. `course.csid` and `course.csrinst` are course ID and course instance

Comment: Could you describe your task in common? What is your higher order task?

Comment: What indexes do you have on the database tables?

Comment: @RomanDibikhin Build a list of students from rules specified by user include/exclude + course/class/student. Where course/class/student might need 1 or 2 fields for key.

Comment: The main issue with this seems to be using `Contains` to test identifier equality...

Comment: @DavidKemp Why? Would joining on multiple identifiers solve anything in this case? Also in my database some tables are coming from legacy system on FoxPro and they all are `nchar(n)` so they all have trailing whitespace, therefore equality checks don't always work on strings. And to make matters worse things are rarely linked by actual ID's.

Comment: @morowinder one of those :O - see my answer, it should point you in the right direction, although it doesn't solve the problem 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're using "Contains", it's difficult, and you'd probably have build a query dynamically, using [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx):

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.False<Course>();
foreach(var opt in options.Where(x => x.type.Equals("course"))
{
    predicate = predicate.Or(course.csid.Contains(opt.identifier) && course.crsinst.Contains(opt.extra_identifier));
}
```

(the first example on the Predicate builder page shows a similar example)